# Issues while Updating drupa/slack to 8.x-1.2

Tags: 8, composer

The site I am working on is using drupal/slack ^1.2 in composer.json file but the module present in the instance and that in composer.lock is the dev version.

I ran a

```
lando composer require drupal/slack:^1.2
```

However, the module is not changing and neither is the composer.lock file.

FYI, The site is running inside lando.

How do I debug this problem?

Additional info

```
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Also the problem only seems to effect the slack module.  The others seem to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried `lando composer remove drupal/slack` and then `lando composer require drupal/slack` again? Does your composer.json have [`"prefer-stable": true`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable) configured yes or no?

Comment: Let me try that suggestion

Comment: Nope not working

Comment: Come on, what does >>Nope not working<< mean? What you typed exactly? Any error messages? Any messages at all? What happened? Please update question. Also maybe try `rm -rf composer.lock && rm -rf vendor/` and then `composer install` again. In a local copy of your site of course.

Comment: Oops missed the second part of your question. Let me check that. Also no error messages. This happens only with this module. The others usually update fine.

Comment: prefer-stable is set to true.

Comment: Your question seems to be "How do I debug composer?" or "Why is composer not working inside of lando?" I think either are off-topic because the former is specific to PHP and the latter is a bug/support request for the lando team. Either way, I would probably include your composer.json and try to replicate without lando.

Comment: Usually composer print some solutions in order to fix your dependency versions problems. So you just need to read the output of your console and execute it :).

Comment: The problem is affecting the slack module only. The others are working fine. So I think the problem could be related to the drupal slack module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. There was a custom module that had it's own composer.json listing the dev version of slack as a dependency.

This seems to have been overriding the root package version.  I got to know this after removing the drupal slack as suggested here but the module remained on the web directory. So figured that some other package was listing it as a dependency.

Doing a grep led me to the file and updating the version in that composer.json and running lando composer update drupal/slack solved the problem.

Thanks for everyone's help.